# Use Oracle Identity federation with Active Directory

Tags: active-directory, saml, federated-identity

I am new to Federation Identity thing.

I am looking to integrate Oracle Identity Federation (OIF) with Active Directory(AD). How can I achieve this ?

I have googled it but didnt find anything relevant.

I know there is Active Directory Federation Service (AD FS) is also there, so I have to do mix and match or how to achieve it "[Link](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff849212%28v=ws.10%29.aspx)" ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes you need to use ADFS, this integrates with AD to extract data and send it using federation.

[Here is a guide to do the integration](https://blogs.oracle.com/dcarru/entry/integrating_adfs_2_0_idp).

Comment: Thanks Stefan for your response.

Comment: My client has asked to use OIF with SharePoint(SP) & AD, So there is no direct way to connect AD to OIF ? and integrate OIF in SP ?

Comment: It also supports multiple domains ?

Comment: Have a look here http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E27559_01/admin.1112/e27239/oam11_sharepoint2010.htm

Comment: I m looking for SP 2013 which I google also but didnt find anything

Comment: I would suggest reading up on Sharepoint integration options, the easiest way is probably to integrate with OIF/OAM using the SAML protocoll. I dont know Sharepoint so I can give any further recomendation without more resarch.

Comment: If you are interested for more help I work as a Security Consultant at Oracle and if you subcontract me Im sure we can find a solution

Comment: Thanks for ur help..will let u know